# Does using malloc to create a string not automatically add a NULL terminator?

Tags: c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <math.h>

char* center(char* s, int n){
    int len = strlen(s);
    size_t newArrayLength = n+1;
    char* newString = malloc(newArrayLength); // did not use size of char, as sizeof(char) is 1, I used n+1 to make space for the end of string character
    if(newString == NULL){
        return("Sorry, could not allocate memory"); //checked allocating memory worked
    }

    int dashes = n - len;                     //number of dashes needed
    
    if(dashes < 0){
        return "Not have enough dashes!!!!!!!!";
    }

    int lsdash= (dashes/2);                   //number of left side dashes
    
    int rsdash = dashes - lsdash;             //number of right side dashes

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

        if(i<lsdash){                        // if within the left dash region, place a dash
            newString[i] = '-';
        }

        else if(i>=lsdash && i<len+lsdash){  // if within the string region, write out the string
            newString[i] = s[i-lsdash];
        }

        else{
            newString[i] = '-';              // else, we are in the right dash region, so place a dash
        }    
    }                                       
    newString[n] = '\0';
    return newString;
}


int main(){
    char* str = "cat";           //original string I wish to place dashes around
    int n = 9;                   // length of new string, that includes dashes
    char* newString = center(str, n);
    printf("%s\n", newString);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is supposed to take a string, in this case `cat`, and surround it with dashes, so that it is in the middle of all the dashes. At the end of the center function, I have a line which manually adds the null terminator character to the string.

My problem is, without this line of code, sometimes but not all the time, I get a random character at the end of my string. I assume this is because the code is reading memory unrelated to the string as it has not come across an '\0' character. Why does this happen, does using malloc to create a char array not add the '\0' necessary to detect the end of the string? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: If you want the allocated memory to be filled with `0`, use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not.

The memory allocated from `malloc` is not guaranteed to be initialized, and reading any part you haven't previously written causes undefined behavior.  In particular you certainly cannot rely on having null characters anywhere within it.

The line where you "manually" add the null terminator is necessary.  Do not remove it.

The `calloc` function does promise to initialize the allocated memory with zero bytes.  In that case, you can be sure that whatever you wrote will be followed by a null terminator (provided you didn't overwrite the last byte).  However, this comes at a runtime cost, and means it unnecessarily initializes many bytes that you will shortly overwrite anyway.

Comment: ...although you can't remove the line that adds the terminator, you might want to move it out of the loop...

Comment: calloc doesn't have a runtime cost on modern operating systems

Comment: @M.M: It's true that memory coming straight from the OS will already be zeroed, and calloc may be able to take advantage of that, when applicable.  However, if it gives you memory which was previously `free`d and not given back to the OS, it will have to be zeroed again.